# Correct setting for mysql pconnect in Code Igniter when handling two different databases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I would just like to confirm if I have the proper settings for mysql pconnect, by default the CI configuration for this one is set to TRUE, after researching some more post and references the advise was to set it to FALSE to avoid problems such as getting "MYSQL Server has gone away". I'm deciding to set it to FALSE because in the CI driver mysql there is a condition that if pconnect is set to false it will tell CI to do a reconnection when working with 2 databases. Currently my app has two database configurations one for mysql and one for oci8. I would like an opinion on this matter if possible a detailed explanation why is should use them.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opted to disable pconnect myself (or, rather, to use the mysqli driver, which disables it) due to finding several idle connections stuck sleeping (which caused me to hit concurrent connections limits).  This happened under a few scenarios, including failed transactions that weren't handled gracefully, application errors that didn't release the persistent connection, etc.

I'm sure that many of my problems would be easier to control in a production environment running stable, tested code, but I have no idea how many "bugs" have come up that were simply residual effects of pconnect nuances.  I've disabled it, and haven't had any problems since.  If I get into scaling issues where connection overhead is really expensive, I'll deal with that when I get to it (Never, EVER, prematurely optimize!).  For now, I can control that pretty well with opcode and memcaching, and complex database queries aren't a problem.

The mysqli driver is newer from my understanding, and I trust those guys wouldn't disable pconnect by default if it wasn't what most people need...

Comment: yeah but having disabled pconnect does Code Igniter automatically reconnect already? or do i still have to configure it in my controller or something?

Comment: If you can, give it a try.  I switched pconnect off on a new project of mine (when I remembered it was on by default), and everything works seamlessly.

Comment: I should clarify: I switched the driver to "mysqli" which has pconnect disabled by default.  I can't comment on the effects of disabling pconnect with the other driver.